# Angular get root path of application on production

Tags: javascript, angular

I have image path from root as you can see from the code below.

```
new VideoCategory("360 grader", "/assets/images/videos/video-category-1.jpg", "360-grader")
```

So, the path `"/assets/images/videos/video-category-1.jpg"` serves fine if my app is hosted in the root folder. But when I host in app in a folder other than root say

http://example.com/subfolder/ then the images does not load obviously. So how do I get the root path of my application in angular?

**What I tried?** I tried to use the `PlatformLocation` and then `origin` and `href`. But they does not seem to work.

```
import { PlatformLocation } from '@angular/common';

export class VideoCategoryService {
  ploc : string;

  constructor(platformLocation: PlatformLocation) {
    console.log((platformLocation as any).location);
    console.log((platformLocation as any).location.href);
    console.log((platformLocation as any).location.origin);
    this.ploc = (platformLocation as any).location.origin;
  }

  getList(callback) {
    const list = [
        new VideoCategory("360 grader", this.ploc + "/assets/images/videos/video-category-1.jpg", "360-grader")
    ];
    callback(list);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the angular CLI? If so, you can pass a flag `--base-href` which sets the base path to which stuff like `assets` resolves. Like so:

```
$ ng build --base-href=/subfolder/
```

Another option would be to set the base HREF in your `index.html`:

```
<base href="/subfolder/">
```

In any case, you shouldn't have to be reliant on `PlatformLocation`, it's a service used internally by the Router to resolve URL patterns (see also [the API docs](https://angular.io/api/common/PlatformLocation)).

Comment: I have already changed base href manually in index.html file. But the image is loading an inner component. I guess I will have to remove the / before assets folder and check again. But what I was actually look for here is a solution to get the path to root folder.